# Cannot install Cordova/Phonegap on system running Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: cordova, ubuntu

I was trying to install cordova/phonegap on my machine running on ubuntu 15.0 following the guide http://madebyknight.com/installing-phonegapcordova-windows-linux/

I have also tried the below two guides but encountered the same problem

http://dasunhegoda.com/installrun-phonegap-ubuntu/797/

http://www.levibotelho.com/development/the-complete-guide-to-running-phonegap-on-ubuntu

while running this commands all i'm getting is the below result

command :

```
npm install –g phonegap@3.4
npm install –g cordova@3.4
```

Result :

```
npm WARN package.json node@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json node@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json node@0.0.0 No README data
npm ERR! 404 Not Found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 '–g' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.19.0-15-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "–g" "phonegap@3.4"
npm ERR! cwd /home/user
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0


npm WARN package.json node@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json node@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json node@0.0.0 No README data
npm ERR! 404 Not Found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 '–g' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.19.0-15-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "–g" "cordova@3.4"
npm ERR! cwd /home/user
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: does your problem solve ?

Comment: No. Sorry for late reply @Pyro

Answer (score 0):

Your nodejs installation is not working correctly. Try reinstalling nodejs and then execute this command. If you look at the error, it is not able to recognise the `-g` global switch indicating issues with your nodejs and npm

Comment: I have reinstalled nodejs several times but facing the same problem again.... thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the wrong hypen sign as mentioned in this:
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1859, you should manually type the command in the terminal (specifically -g) or try `sudo npm install -g cordova@3.4` it may work

If you have still have the same error this url may help you:http://www.himpfen.com/install-apache-cordova-ubuntu/

First check if NPM is installed properly by checking `nodejs -v` and if it works try installing try the next steps for installing cordova